# What is the solution for this particular integral (ODE)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is finding the general solution of the following ODE:
$$
x''= - \gamma -4x
$$
where $\gamma$ is just a constant, and boundary conditions are $x(0)= - \gamma/4$  and   $x'(0)=2$.

From my calculation, I got the complementary function of $A\sin(2t)+B\cos(2t)$.

I'm trying to find the the particular integral and what I normally do is for example if the function $= Ce^{kx}$, I make particular integral $= Ae^{kx}$ etc..
However, for this type, I'm not sure which ansatz I should use.

So can you tell me how to solve particular integral of this equation.

Answer (score 1):

You have a right side of the type $−γ=Ce^{0t}$ and thus make the ansatz $Ae^{0t}$.

Or you could substitute $u=4x+γ$ to get $u''+4u=0$.

Comment: So if Xp = Ae^0t, what would be Xp' and Xp''?

Comment: As $X_p$ is a constant, its derivatives will be zero.